# Currency troubles with my shipping tables!

Tags: checkout, shipping

So I created a shipping table (csv file) and set the cost for standard delivery for example for the USA to 17.00 (€) but when the customer is trying to checkout out he will see 14.20(€) as shippment cost. How can I fix this? My buissnes is located in Europe

Comment: check you tax settings.